# How make restriction on the data property to have a distinct value for individuals

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have a class `Sensor`, and each sensor `hasID` data property. Each sensor has a distinct `ID#` which cannot take by another sensor. In other word, two sensors cannot have a same `ID#`. How can I represent this?

Comment: Why do you need the ID# as an object of a data property instead of using the sensor URI as unique identifier?

Comment: Because I need to track each sensor based on the ID# in my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a HasKey axiom on Sensor specifying hasID as a property. HasKey is described in the OWL 2 specs.

Comment: That's how I did it in the Protege `hasID some integer SubClassOf Sensor` but it seems that it is not correct because it allows two sensors have the same `ID#` any idea?

Comment: Enforcement of keys requires a reasoner. Which reasoner are you using?

Comment: I used FaCT++ on Protege 4.3

Comment: FaCT++ does not support keys at the moment (as of version 1.6.4). I recommend trying HermiT or Pellet, they are both available for Protege 4.3

Comment: I used HermiT 1.3.8, it couldn't catch it. I wrote my condition under the `General class axiom` on Protege. Am I doing something wrong or just because I am using the old Protege

Comment: It could be the individuals are inferred to be sameAs instead of causing inconsistency. Try declaring all Sensor instances as different from each other.